# Turning HTML/CSS site in PHP by way of includes hurt google ranking or effect proper indexing

Tags: php, seo

The question is pretty straight forward. I've seen some questions similar but not what I need an answer to. So lets say I splice the entire site and use includes for almost everything. Navigation, about us, etc,. Will this effect google ranking and indexing? Will google view the site by parsing the php when it passes an include or will it index it as a blank site. As most all of it will be inside separate includes files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Google should not be able to see your php script.

Comment: Don't understand the answer. If google can not see the script than it will not index properly right? It needs to view the site in full to doso.

Comment: PHP is a hypertext processor. It outputs only HTML. What PHP outputs is what Google will see. You could "include" each line of HTML on your homepage in PHP and Google will be none the wiser.